# swapon command is not listing the lvm name

Tags: lvm, disk-usage, swap, fdisk

I am facing issues with `swapon -s` command. It is displaying some other filename instead of my lvm name which i have given ( swap is LVM partition )

`swapon -s` command is not listing my LVM Name for my swap memory. Check out my result.

**Result :**

```
[root@arunraj opt]# swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition   14032888    0   -1
```

**LVM Names** are follows :

```
[root@arunraj opt]# lvs
  LV      VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_home VolGroup -wi-ao----   5.00g                                             
  lv_root VolGroup -wi-ao---- 260.00g                                             
  lv_swap VolGroup -wi-ao----  13.38g
```

I have checked the link between the swap file name and my lvm name. It is present.

```
[root@arunraj opt]# ll /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jun 13 18:46 /dev/VolGroup/lv_swap -> ../dm-1
```

I believe that is why i am not getting swap space in the following disk free command `df -h`.

**Result :**

```
[root@arunraj opt]# df -h

Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root  256G  178G   65G  74% /
tmpfs                          63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                     485M   33M  427M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home  5.0G  138M  4.6G   3% /home
```

> I have tried `free -g` command. It is listing my swap space. But `df -h` is not listing my swap space. I don't know what is missing in my configuration. Please help me to fix this configuration issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LVM is built on the device mapper code in Linux. This means that all the LVM commands are actually creating and manipulating device mapper devices. So, the symlink to `../dm-1` is normal.

If you are curious about the device mapper, you can inspect its state using `dmsetup`, e.g. `dmsetup info /dev/dm-1`.

As for why you cannot see the swap device in `df`, that is also normal. `df` shows free diskspace in mounted filesystems. Swap space is not a file system, and it is therefore not shown. (It will not be shown as a mounted filesystem when you run `mount` either.)